# Error in hiphop mysql connection

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, hiphop, hhvm

I am new to hiphop. I have installed hhvm on ubuntu 12.04. installation is complete now and I have started hhvm server and its  working fine with php code having no database. But when I am running php application having database connection  on hhvm server it is giving error

`could not connect to mysql server:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have accessed mysql through terminal and created database and tables. But I am not able to access phpmyadmin. Do I need to install phpmyadmin for hhvm server? Please guide me how can I proceed ahead?

Comment: You need to configure your application with proper database credentials. Are you sure the `root` user has no password?